# Create different Fresnel lenses from different curves using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, 3d-printing, mathematics

Create different Fresnel lenses from different curves using geometry nodes.

I'm trying to create different types of Fresnel lenses **from different shaped curves** (to see what they look like when **"revolved" to a circle**).

`My thoughts:`

1. Use mesh island index (to get each split curve section)
2. Use set position node to line them up then "revolve" into a circle.

**The issue I'm having is getting each separated part / section of the curve.  I'm trying to avoid using boolean difference since that can be heavy cpu wise (but if that's the only way I'll do it.)**

Here's an example of the curve (**in red** I'm trying to section into parts to create the lens)
[image: img1]

Main video Fresnel Lens simulation with audio:
https://www.youtube.com/shorts/9JX0Zdc6MaU

Also how a Fresnel Lens works.
https://youtu.be/_nBNnlu6Rqo

**PS:  I'm using geometry nodes so it can be parametric since I would like to try / swap in and out multiple different curves quickly (and these will be 3D printed).**

So in the end it will look like this

[image: imgb]

[image: imgc]

There would have to be several of these "cutting intersection" nodes but I limited it to 1 and showed it in an animation.

[image: imgd]

Attached Blend File showing boolean cutting..

[image]

Comment: `Convert to Mesh` and `Split Edges` might be helpful. Can you share your blend file so we can look at it with a concrete example?

Comment: @quellenform I uploaded the file with how I would get the sections using "boolean cutting".  There would have to be several of these nodes but I limited it to 1 and showed it in an animation.

Comment: Is this an aspherical or spherical lens? Does the lens have to be a mesh as a starting point, or can this also be created via GN? (Which would be easier in the case of a spherical lens). In short, does it have to be optically exact, or is it just about the appearance itself?

Comment: @quellenform It's aspherical the curves can change curvature.  The starting point can be GN but I thought it would be easier to do as an example just showing the curve. I'm trying to make it with accurate dimensions since it will be 3D printed.

Comment: Hm, then I'm afraid you won't get around boolean operations as long as a mesh is the starting point and the curvature is individually controlled by the mesh. With a spherical lens this would have been less problematic in GN, because then there would have been a purely mathematical solution. Hmm, I'm still thinking about this. How high is the resolution of the mesh in the end? Because the example shows a rather unrealistic resolution for a real lens.

Comment: And just out of interest: May I ask what kind of printer you are using here? Because that's new to me, that you can also print optical lenses (at least for home use).

Comment: @quellenform I have access to a Resin-SLA and FDM (note this is for testing but I wanted to make it as parametric as possible so I could try different things out).  The size that will be printed is 70mm diameter (the size of a magnifying glass) https://blog.prusa3d.com/3d-printed-lens-and-other-transparent-objects_31231/

Comment: Which data can we use here as input to specify how the cuts should be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: fresnel]

[image]

Here. A speedy (no booleans - under 3ms) parametric fresnel lens node group with Plano-Convex, Equi-Convex, and Bi-Convex options. You can adjust steps, scaling and width. Tip: At 1 step it makes a normal lens. Requires Blender 4.1 or above.

---

The basic workings:

[image: Arc to Fresnel]

Rather than boolean we can use an (Arc) curve primitive nodes and some trigonometry to draw separate pieces of the lens profile. And then a set position node to offset each piece.

[image: Explanation]

As an example for the green segment above: the radius of the lens forms the hypotenuse of a triangle, whilst the origin to each segment gives the adjacent lengths.

- Blue triangle (Arc) node start point
- Red triangle (Arc) node end point

Because we have both a hypotenuse and the adjacent lengths we can use the trigonometry equation of cosine to get the angle for the arc inputs, that is: arccos(θ)= hypotenuse / adjacent

[image: Fresnel Arc Segment]
In Blender: Arccosine and subtraction between each lens segment to get the arc start and end points.

[image: Fresnel Lens Repeat Zone]
Organize this into a repeat zone with an offset and viola.